# Header of file compiled by bluespec

Tags: verilog, reverse-engineering, reverse, riscv, ctf

I have a file with the .bo extension.
After some researches it seems be built with bluespec which is use with risc-V architecture.
My objective is to reverse this file.

When i do:

```
file myfile.bo
myfile.bo: data
```

So, I don't know if it's a good "format" for the file. Or what must be the return of the file command on a .bo file?
What is the basic header file for a verilog file?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: bluespec is bluespec, verilog is verilog.  These are different languages. They are not compatible. a bluespec tool can generate verilog. What is your question?

Comment: I have a file .bo which is generated by a bluespec tool. But when I do a file in it the result is data.
If i don't do mistakes .bo is a verilog file extension and this file is linked to a TB.bs (which is a testbench in verilog if i don't do mistakes).
I wanted to know what is the result of an hexdump -C on a basic verilog file and the result of a file on the same file.

Comment: this is definitely not a common verilog extension which are `.v`, and `.vh`, there are `.sv` and `.svh` for system veirlog. In general some verilog compilers do not care about extension at all. in any cas `bo` and `bs` are definitely **not** common verilog extensions. You have to look inside the file to find out what it its. And you need to use a verilog compiler which does not care or can configure file extensions.

Comment: So I have the confirmation my file is the byte code of verilog file so it's was not enough clear for me when I asked the question.
thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Verilog is definately not the language format of preference for using other software files except C,C++...I'd suggest to convert the bluespec file into C and then maybe you can get lucky.

Comment: what are you trying to say? bluespec, as verilog are hardware description languages. c and c++ are not. It would be difficult to convert either of them. Also OP does not mention c/c++.